Can someone running Apache Zeppelin 0.11.1 (or previous versions) check the JSON response for a Notebook API Endpoint?
I have a 0.7.1 Zeppelin environment set up that works without problem.  I recently set up 2 new environments using Zeppelin version 0.11.1.  I have everything I need working in those new environments, however I have discovered an issue.
The Notebook Rest API for "Get the status of all paragraphs" returns the JSON response in the format as described in the documentation.  https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#get-the-status-of-all-paragraphs
The documentation for 0.11.1 is the same as 0.7.1 https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.11.1/usage/rest_api/notebook.html#get-the-status-of-all-paragraphs
Using 0.11.1 the response I'm getting does not match the expected response in the documentation.
Does anyone have 0.11.1 running and can check what response they are getting for this API endpoint?
Anyone that has a version above 0.7.1 does your response return the same as documented?
Or maybe there is something else I'm missing with configuration?
Documentation Sample Response for /api/notebook/job/[noteid]:
{
"status": "OK",
"body": [
{
"id":"20151121-212654_766735423",
"status":"FINISHED",
"finished":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:40 KST 2015",
"started":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:39 KST 2015"
},
{
"progress":"1",
"id":"20151121-212657_730976687",
"status":"RUNNING",
"finished":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:35 KST 2015",
"started":"Tue Nov 24 14:21:40 KST 2015"
}
]
}
The response I am receiving for /api/notebook/job/[noteid]
{
"status": "OK",
"body": {
"id": "2KBRPY3PH",
"isRunning": false,
"paragraphs": [
{
"id": "paragraph_1729804797522_424341209",
"status": "READY",
"progress": "0"
}
]
}
}
